# My Laravel project folder was in "D:\projects " xampp folder so i changed to "D:\xampp", but now i cant connect to the database

Tags: php, laravel

My OS had a fault so i moved my laravel project to a new xampp folder after installing a new OS. i prepared the development environment as before. The problem is i cannot connect to the database even after configuring the env file. When i run `migrate` its failing with the following error and  showing the old path i was using.

laravel is trying to connect to a database that am no longer using. the project is in a new folder and its bringing the old path which obviously would fail. The thing is it needs to use the new path rather than this `D:\Projects\htdocs\zipad\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671` My project was moved to `D:\xampp\.................`

### error message

```
     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
    (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = zipad and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') 

  at D:\Projects\htdocs\zipad\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this- 
   >prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
```

what configuration do i need for it to pick the new xampp folder path my project is in?

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/595/how-to-solve-xampp-mysql-error-2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it

Comment: @Rwd laravel is trying to connect to a database that am no longer using. the project is in a new folder and its bringing the old path which obviously would fail. The thing is it needs to use the new path rather than this `D:\Projects\htdocs\zipad\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671` My new project is in `D:\xampp\.................`

Comment: Maybe it's your .env file. Did you change the connection informations inside it?